# Neo4j / Cypher: Is CREATE UNIQUE deprecated?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

When I write a simple Cypher query like this:

```
MATCH (r:Person {name:'Jon'})
MATCH (s:Person {name:'Ana'})
CREATE UNIQUE (r)-[:FRIEND_OF]->(s)
```

I'm receiving an alert messsage in the Neo4j browser. The alert message says:

> **The RULE planner is not available in the current CYPHER version, the
>   query has been run by an older CYPHER version.** CREATE UNIQUE is
>   unsupported for current CYPHER version, the query has been execute by
>   an older CYPHER version

Here a print screen of the alert message:

[image: Alert message]

I searched by this message in the Neo4j Github and did not find anything. Also the docs has no mention to any depreciation.

**My question is:** Is CREATE UNIQUE deprecated? Why?

I'm using Neo4j 3.2.1.

Thanks.

**PS:** I know my query can be refactoring. It is only an example. Also all refactoring made in the query using `CREATE UNINQUE` show the same alert message in the Neo4j browser.

Comment: I can't answer your question, but as an FYI (and you may already be aware) but I think you can refactor your query like so `MATCH (r:Person {name:'Jon'}), (s:Person {name:'Ana'}) CREATE UNIQUE (r)-[:FRIEND_OF]->(s)` (aka get ride of the second `match` and replace with a `,`)

Answer (score 6):

CREATE UNIQUE is set to be completely replaced by MERGE. So your syntax would be :

```
MATCH (r:Person {name:'Jon'})
MATCH (s:Person {name:'Ana'})
MERGE (r)-[:FRIEND_OF]->(s)
```

Regards,
Tom

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
MATCH (lft:Person {name:'Jon'}),(rgt)
WHERE rgt.name IN ['Ana']
CREATE UNIQUE (lft)-[r:KNOWS]->(rgt)
RETURN r
```

note that you can search for multiple names too like this

```
MATCH (lft:Person {name:'Jon'}),(rgt)
WHERE rgt.name IN ['Ana','Maria']
CREATE UNIQUE (lft)-[r:KNOWS]->(rgt)
RETURN r
```